# Я был более всё-таки не прав / неправ, чем прав

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я был более всё-таки не прав / неправ, чем прав.

> Мы были, надо признать, немного не правы / неправы.

Comment: Предложите ваше решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) *Я был всё-таки более **неправ**, чем прав.*

***Более неправ*** — сравнительная степень краткого качественного прилагательного ***неправ.*** Это количественная оценка признака (сравнить: совершенно/абсолютно неправ), поэтому слитное написание.

(2) *Мы были, надо признать, немного **неправы**.*

Здесь аналогичная ситуация, то есть наречие меры и степени ***немного***; количественная оценка признака, выраженного прилагательным ***неправ.***

**[Карта слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2)**

**НЕПРАВЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -прав, -а, -о. 1. Поступающий, говорящий **ошибочно, неправильно**. Человек, н. в своих действиях. Вы неправы, отказавшись подписать заявление. Считать друг друга неправыми. 2. Высок. **Несправедливый;** противоречащий праву (1.П.; 3 зн.). Н. суд. Н-ое обвинение. * Неправ твой, о Небо, святой приговор! (Лермонтов).

**ПРАВЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; прав, -а, -о. 1. **Ни в чём не виновный,** не имеющий за собой вины, проступка. Разберись, кто из них прав. Чувствую себя правым. [] в зн. сущ. Досталось и правому и виноватому. 2. только **кратк.** **Правильно говорящий**, думающий или поступающий; не совершивший ошибки. Ты прав: это большая редкость. Вы совершенно правы! 3. **Высок**. Заключающий в себе правду (3 зн.); справедливый. Бой святой и п. Бороться за п-ое дело. * Дай гневу правому созреть (Блок). Боже правый! в зн. межд. Разг. =Боже праведный! Боже правый, он же упадёт!